# Stuck on solving recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I'm trying to find formula for the following sequence.

1, 3, 6, 10, 15...

Recursive formula is pretty straightforward

[image]

***My attempt to solve it:***

1. Homogeneous solution

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
2. Particular solution

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

I stuck here. A bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $a_n-a_{n-1}=n$

$a_n$ can be at most quadratic  $a_n=An^2+Bn+C$ where $A,B,C$ are arbitrary constants

Now  $a_{n-1}=A(n-1)^2+B(n-1)+C$

So, $An^2+Bn+C-\{A(n-1)^2+B(n-1)+C\}=n$

$\implies 2An-(A-B)=n$

Equating the different powers of $n$ we get $A-B=0$ and $2A=1$

So, $a_n=\frac{n^2}2+\frac n2+C$

For $n=1=a_1=\frac12+\frac12+C\implies C=0$

Comment: You already know that $C$ will vanish as it is solution of the homogeneous part.

Comment: A^2 - B = 0, i guess

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev, how do you find $A^2?$

Comment: ah, sorry, silly mistake, incorrectly decomposed A(n-1)^2

Comment: It is said nowhere that $a_0=0$. You can add any $C$ to your particular solution, it will still be a particular solution, as constants are solutions of the homogeneous equation. So the most natural choice is $C=0$.

Comment: @julien, not sure what you meant, but I just showed how $C=0$

Comment: I think my last comment answers that. But let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev, I removed the usage of $a_0$ as pointed out by juilen

Comment: Your manipulation is unusual, but I promise that's the last time I try. The particular solution you computed has $a_1=1$, which forces indeed this $C=0$. But to express the general solution, theory says you need to add the general solution of the homogeneous part, say $D$. Then you need to check $a_1$ again, and find $D=0$. So you do it twice. Whereas, if you set $C=0$ from the start in your search for a particular solution (without paying attention to the intial condition, that's how we do) and then add the $D$ from the homogneous part, you then find $D=0$ looking at $a_1$. Just once.

Answer (score 2):

Try $a_n=An^2+Bn$ for a particular solution.